# Set up a homepage landing page that doesn't show every time

Tags: wordpress, html

Not sure how to properly ask this question, but a customer that's using Wordpress asked me to set up a homepage that can split off into two places but not load every time a user goes to the "home" page.

Say you go to xyz.com and you're presented with two links, XYZ Air & XYZ Sea. But ideally, when someone would go back to the homepage, they would just see whichever's homepage they clicked on.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie when an user click on a link in the "full" homepage.
And when the user come back to the home page you need to check the value of the cookie, in this way you can show the appropriate link.
Is this a possible solution?